# Unknown output: "AirDrop: collectionView..." when using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I am an ios developer. Recently I'm using the UIDocumentInteractionController to open my file in other apps. When the code runs to a line that called the  `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated` method, a weird string appears in the xcode output:

`AirDrop: collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:, orientation:1, sectionInset: {0, 13, 0, 13}`

And this string only appears when I run the app on ipad with ios7.0.2, and not appear in iphone4s with ios 7.1.3.

This output worries me, I have no idea why this came out. It's not a warning or an exception, and besides the output, everything runs well and the candidate apps list can show up correctly and also the file can be opened successfully by the app selected.

But why this string appears? It's definitely not from the code I wrote. Looks like it's a function signature related to Airdrop. Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: It's probably just some debug logging apple engineers have left on by accident. I wouldn't worry too much about it

Comment: @ccjensen I agree. Thank you.